# Android ConnectivityManager is not seeing permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android, eclipse, android-networking, eclipse-adt

I have simple code that wants to read the state of network connection. I've added permission to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

My code that tries to access network state:

```
    ConnectivityManager conmgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ninfo = conmgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

And the error that is thrown:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(7650): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10080 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

I've long tried to find any error, but everything seems to be spelled correctly. It seems like the new version of AndroidManifest is not deployed to device. I've tried to clean project in Eclipse, uninstall app from phone, but nothing is working, I get the same communicate again. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess, maybe the tag is not placed correctly, try putting it before the application tag.

Comment: Another wild guess: `<useR-permission />` - this typo only here or in the code too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

instead of

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Yes, of course it was it, I was looking at permission string, I thought there is any validation of AndroidManifest.xml, but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: I'm confuse of : does this resolved your problem? in my search, there is not `user-permission` in android.

Comment: @VinceStyling you need to have a file called AndroidManifest.xml and in there <uses-permission />. The OP misspelled uses and wrote user instead

Answer (score 0):

Delete the imports of all kinds that has to do with NetworkInfo like Java.net packages or any other.. Re-import

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30511411)